# Why does my thread just hang after a certain number of loops?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I've made an application to select specific `.xml` files, open them (into a `TStringList`), and check for specific numbers, then move the to a folder so that I can upload to another section of our company.

Here's the problem.

After around 9728 items moved, it just stops, for no reason that I can think of.

It doesn't show any error, just keeps hanging.

Maybe it's my code that's doing it after some time, but I hope you guys can help!

I'm using Delphi 2006.

**Thread Code:**

```pascal
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, dblookup, FileCtrl, ExtDlgs, StrUtils;

type
  FThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    arquivo: string;
    Lista3: TStringList;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdateMemo; overload;
  end;

implementation

uses AcharArquivos3;

{ Important: Methods and properties of objects in visual components can only be
  used in a method called using Synchronize, for example,

      Synchronize(UpdateCaption);

  and UpdateCaption could look like,

    procedure FThread.UpdateCaption;
    begin
      Form1.Caption := 'Updated in a thread';
    end; }

{ FThread }

procedure FThread.UpdateMemo;
begin
  Lista3.Add(Arquivo);
end;

procedure FThread.Execute;
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  Lista2: TStringList;
  Caminho: string;
  CaminhoOriginal: string;
  Origem: string;
  Destino: string;
begin
  inherited;
  Caminho := Form3.Dir;
  CaminhoOriginal := Form3.Edit1.Text;
  Lista2 := TStringList.Create;
  Lista3 := TStringList.Create;
  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Caminho) + '*.*', faAnyFile or faDirectory, SR) = 0 then
  try
    repeat
      if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) = 0 then
      begin
        if (ExtractFileExt(SR.Name) = '.xml') and not (Pos(Sr.Name, Lista3.Text) > 0) then
          Lista2.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Caminho) + SR.name);
          if Pos(Form3.NCM, Lista2.Text) > 0 then
          begin
            Origem := Caminho + '\' + SR.name;
            Destino := CaminhoOriginal + '\' + 'Incluir' + '\' + SR.Name;
            Arquivo := ChangeFileExt(SR.name, '');
            Lista3.Add(Arquivo);
            MoveFile(Pchar(Origem), Pchar(Destino));
            Synchronize(Self.UpdateMemo);
          end;
        end
      else if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') and (Sr.Name <> 'Incluir') then
      begin
        Caminho := (IncludeTrailingBackslash(Caminho) + SR.Name);  // Recursão
      end;
    until (FindNext(Sr) <> 0) and (Sr.Name = 'Incluir');
  finally
    FindClose(SR);
    ShowMessage('Pesquisa Concluida!');
    Form3.Button6.Enabled := True;
    Form3.Button5.Enabled := True;
    Form3.Button2.Enabled := True;
    Form3.Memo3.Lines.Add(Lista3.Text);
  end;
end;

end.
```

**VCL Code:**

```pascal
unit AcharArquivos3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, dblookup, FileCtrl, ExtDlgs, StrUtils;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button2: TButton;
    OpenPictureDialog1: TOpenPictureDialog;
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    Button5: TButton;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Button6: TButton;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Path:String;
    NCM: String;
    Origem: string;
    Destino: string;
    Dir: String;
    Lista2: TStringList;
    Lista: TStringList;
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit5;

function WUserName: String;
var
  nSize: DWord;
begin
  nSize := 1024;
  SetLength(Result, nSize);
  if GetUserName(PChar(Result), nSize) then
    SetLength(Result, nSize-1)
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

//Pegando a pasta dos XML
procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  chosenDirectory : string;
begin
  if SelectDirectory('Select a directory', 'C:\' + WUserName + 'Documents', chosenDirectory) then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := chosenDirectory;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Seleção de Pasta Abortada');
end;

procedure TForm3.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: String;
begin
  if (Memo3.GetTextLen() > 0) then
  begin
    SaveDialog1.FileName := 'ListaEncontrados';
    SaveDialog1.DefaultExt := 'txt';
    SaveDialog1.Filter := 'Text file|*.txt|Word file|*.doc';
    SaveDialog1.Title := 'Salve o arquivo de Lista';
    Memo3.Lines.Delete(Memo3.Lines.Count-1);
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
      Memo3.Lines.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
    SaveDialog1.Free;
    Memo3.Lines.Clear;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Nenhum Arquivo Excluido');
end;

procedure TForm3.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vThread : FThread;
begin
  if ComboBox1.Text = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Por Favor escolha um NCM para procura');
    Exit;
  end;
  if Edit1.Text = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Por Favor Selecione ou Digite um Diretório');
    Exit;
  end;
  if ComboBox1.Text = '2402 - Cigarros' then
    NCM := '<NCM>2402';
  Dir := Edit1.Text;
  if not DirectoryExists(Dir + '\' + 'Incluir') then
  begin
    CreateDir(Dir + '\' + 'Incluir.');
  end;
  Button6.Enabled := False;
  Button5.Enabled := False;
  Button2.Enabled := False;
  vThread := FThread.Create(True);
  vThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  VThread.Resume;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You cannot access the user interface from a worker thread.

Comment: Did you even read the comment that is still in your code? "_**Important: Methods and properties of objects in visual components can only be used in a method called using Synchronize**_" - and the only time you do so is unnecessary (because you aren't accessing the UI in that), but in so many other cases you access the UI without using `Synchronize()`. What so far worked did only so by chance.

Comment: @kelvinKlein I was just about to say the same thing AmigoJack said. You clearly did not heed the big warning given to you about the thread class. What you describe is very likely a deadlock scenario due to lack of proper synchronization with the main UI thread (and that is just the *least* of what can go wrong when you don't synchronize with the UI thread correctly).

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Thanks for the help guys(AmigoJack and fpiette too)! I found out there was some errors right after I posted it here haha, mainly until (FindNext(Sr) <> 0) **and (Sr.Name = 'Incluir');**, It shouldn't be there in the first place, after debugging found out what was happening. Now the code is working! Changed the Synchronized event too.

Comment: @KelvinKlein I didn't go through all of the code logic, but one thing I do notice is in: `if not DirectoryExists(Dir + '\' + 'Incluir') then begin CreateDir(Dir + '\' + 'Incluir.'); end;` I'm assuming the trailing `.` on the `CreateDir()` is a mistake? Also, this block of code can be simplified by using `ForceDirectories(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir) + 'Incluir');` In fact, your use of ```\``` vs `IncludeTrailingBackslash()` is quite inconsistent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was actually testing one vs the other, because part of this code is from an old project of mine! After I got the Loop right I was going to make it more standardized and consistent within itself. But If you see any other part that you think could use some fixing I'm open ears!